# Python: 'unsupported operand type(s)' error

Tags: python, unix

I'm using Python on UNIX.

I have this code that is supposed to take a single input Z and go through al the values of A from A=Z to A=3Z, and find the largest binding energy  per nucleon (Binding Energy/A). The code looks like:

```
Z = int(input('An atomic Number '))
B_max = 0
A_max = 0

for A in xrange(Z,3*Z+1):  

      B1 = calc_binding_energy(A,Z) #calculates the binding energy 
                                    #for all the values of A

      B2 = float(B1/A)  #finds the energy per nucleon 

      if B2 > B_max:  
          B_max = B1/A  #Then if it is the max it goes back to that 
                        #calculation for the energy per nucleon

          A_max = A #Goes back to find A for the greatest energy

print(A_max)

print (B_max)
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

When I changed the Z input to a float it gave me this error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B1` is a `NoneType`. `calc_binding_energy` is probably not returning a number like you're expecting. You need to paste/examine `calc_binding_energy`